# Can you change menu background color and font size of the Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, themes, accessibility

I know you can change elements of web pages and some aspects of the outer "chrome" via custom themes, font family settings, etc.  What I can't seem to find is any way to change the background of the settings menu (and submenus) in Chrome.  I would prefer it to be a dark them vs. the black text on white.

A similar, related issue is being able to manipulate the overall size of all chrome elements, be they menu fonts, tab fonts and sizes, and icon sizes. My elderly mother, who's having a harder and harder time seeing things due to macular degeneration, would benefit greatly if I could configure these items, as she currently has to use a magnifying glass to read some items.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know i havent found a way to do that which means that if its possible then its probaly hardcoded like file explorer. Which leaves you with two options. 1)Possibly windowblinds with skin studio may be able to help or 2)windows style builder which allows you to completley change the entire msstyles file in file explorer. Other than that it might work with chrome but im not sure. Hope this helps!